# Wait for fetching data from Firebase before return

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have the following code:

**UPDATE:**

```js
const showEvent = (eventLink) => {
  let {events
  } = database
  let staffMembers = ""
  let scenesList = ""
  const staffMembersContainer = $('.staff-members')
  const scenesContainer = $('.scenes')
  const eventsGrid = $('#events-grid')
  const eventHeader = $('#events-grid h2')
  const eventKey = eventLink.getAttribute('data-key')
  const {
    name,
    staff,
    scenes
  } = events[eventKey]
  eventHeader.innerText = name
  eventsGrid.classList.toggle("hidden")
  Object.keys(staff).forEach(role => {
    const staffMember = staff[role]
    staffMembers += Staff(role, staffMember)
  })
  staffMembersContainer.innerHTML = staffMembers
  Object.keys(scenes).forEach(scene => {
    scenesList += Scene(scenes[scene])
  })
  scenesContainer.innerHTML = scenesList
}

const Staff = (role, staffMember) => {
  const {
    name
  } = database.profiles[staffMember[0]]
  return `
     <li>
       <p>${role}:</p>
       <p>${name}</p>
     </li>
  `
}

const Scene = (id) => {
  let promises = []
  const {
    name,
    concerts
  } = database.scenes[id]
  let concertList = ""

  concerts.forEach(concert => {
    promises.push(
      Concert(concert).then(bandName => {
        concertList += `<li><p>${bandName}</p></li>`
      })
    )
  })
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    return `
    <li class="scene">
      <p>Scene ${name}:</p>
      <ul>
        ${concertList}
      </ul>
    </li>
    `
  })
}

const Concert = (id) => {
  const bandId = database.concerts[id].band
  return firebase.database().ref(`/bands/${bandId}/name`).once('value').then(snap => {
    return snap.val()
  })
}
```

So I would like to generate two lists, one containing the Staff members, the other one is containing lists of scenes, where scenes themselves are lists of Band names. I only could get plain HTML elements until I found out, that I should probably wait until the data is fetched from Firebase. As this is my first try with promises, the code is a bit messy, and probably is broken on several points.

If someone would have the time to help, I would extremely appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Could you try removing this first return keyword before firebase.database ... cause in this line you return the promise itself .Please let us know if this resolves.

Comment: No, it does not help. :/ Instead of [object Promise], I get undefined returned

Comment: Would you share your data structure's ss to clarify the question ?

Comment: The `Concert` function is asynchronous, you need to wait for it to finish. You need to call it like `Concert(id).then({ ... })`

Comment: I updated the question with more description, and code.